# Is cherry-pick works from Master to Branch (Master commit --> Branch)?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I know cherry works from Branch to Master(Branch commit -->  Master).  But, Is cherry-pick works from Master to Branch (Master commit -->  Branch)?

Comment: Cherry pick should work from any source branch to any destination branch.  In its simplest form, it just drops a new commit onto some target branch, from a source SHA-1.

Comment: Yes, branches are just labels for commits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. You are the one that brings meaning to your branches.

The names we have all agreed upon using, like `master`, `develop`, `feature/A` etc. is a general convention amongst users of git. There is nothing more special between `master` and `develop` other than the meaning we give it, which in consiquence leads us the way how to use these branches.

`git cherry-pick` doesn't care that you are picking from `feature/a` or from `master`.

> git-cherry-pick - Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits.
>
> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

Whether or not you think is a good idea to cherry-pick from master is a question you have to answer yourself (or maybe your dev team).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just trying to know the limits for cherry-pick.